# Error Referencing wp_users as Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, myisam, wordpress

I'm fairly new to SQL. I'm trying to create a FK for one of my tables (`time_sheet`) to one of the Wordpress tables (`wp_users`). But I'm hitting an error and I'm not entirely sure why that is.

This is my SQL statement to create the table `time_sheet`:

```
Create table Time_Sheets
(
 id bigint AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    project_id varchar(255) not null,
    username varchar(250) not null,
    task varchar(255) not null,
    description varchar(255) not null,
    hours int(10) not null,
    time_date varchar(255) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES Time_Sheet_Projects(project_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (task) REFERENCES Task_List(name),
    FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES wp_users(display_name),
    CHECK (hours > 0)
)
```

Here's an image of the Wordpress database schema:

[image: Schema]

When I take out this line `FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES wp_users(display_name),` the query run perfectly fine.

I've check the name/column name and they are correct. I'm not sure why this isn't working.

`show create table wp_users`

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_users` (
 `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_login` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `user_pass` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `user_nicename` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `user_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `user_url` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `user_registered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `user_activation_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `user_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `display_name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 KEY `user_login_key` (`user_login`),
 KEY `user_nicename` (`user_nicename`),
 KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Edit: So it turned out the database engine being different was the problem. After switching wp_users to InnoDB, everything is working nicely.

Comment: The `CHECK` clause is recognized, but ignored.  Do not plan on it having any effect.

Answer (score 2):

The MyISAM engine doesn't support foreign keys. Use the InnoDB engine instead.

Other observations:

The referenced table has no index on `display_name`. As per documentation, it is required to have an index on the referenced field.

It is better however to use the `ID` field from `wp_users` table to be referenced, and use this ID to lookup `display_name`, like:

```
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES wp_users(id)
```

In addition, change the field in the `time_sheet` table from `username varchar(250) not null,` to `user_id BIGINT not null...`

Comment: ok great, I found a [link](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mysql/myisam-to-innodb/) that shows how to convert it. Hope everything goes smoothly afterward. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it!

Comment: This won't work, as the wp_user ID column is an `UNSIGNED` value, which inhibits it being used as a foreign key reference.

Answer (score 1):

For a foreign key field to work it must have the same exact data type as the field it's referencing - this includes attributes.

I was just pulling my hair out over the exact same thing but it worked using the following column definition:

```
user_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

The thing that had been getting me is I hadn't set my column to `UNSIGNED` - this is an attribute which prevents negative values being stored. Once the column definition matches, including attributes, you can then use the standard `FOREIGN KEY` syntax:

```
FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES wp_users (ID)
```